# onclick issue on Linear layout in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout`, inside it i have a `HorizontalScrollView`, inside it i have 10 images with linear layout. I want to set listener on `RelativeLayout` not on images how I do it.

> below is my code.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ortext">

<HorizontalScrollView
     android:id="@+id/hscroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#f4ede7"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:scrollbars="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
          android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img6"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/image1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use onTouchListener to control widget touches.

Answer (score 0):

Set `onClickListener` on `RelativeLayout`

```
RelativeLayout rlMain=findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
rlMain.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Your code here
    }
});
```

before that remove  from `RelativeLayout`

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to make it look like

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ortext">
```

And Add  `android:clickable="false"` All other child of `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add listener to your RelativeLayout it's similar to how you set Listners to your view's.

```
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    rl.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        //Your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView instead of HorizontalScrollView

then you can easily get onClick listner for your imageview by decalaring custom recyclerview adapter.

Make click listener in bindView

add this line in gradle

```
{
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

then add recycler view in your xml file (activity_main.xml)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then In MainActivity.java RecyclerView

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 ArrayList<String> imagesUrls = new ArrayList<>();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // ...
     // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
     RecyclerView rvImages = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

 //get images from your method
 imagesUrls = getImageUrls();



   // Set layout manager to position the items
    rvImages .setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

     // Create adapter passing in the sample user data
     ImageViewAdapter adapter = new ImageViewAdapter (MainActivity.this,);
     // Attach the adapter to the recyclerview to populate items
     rvImages .setAdapter(adapter);
     // That's all!
     }
}
```

Adapter class

```
package yourpackage.name;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ImageViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewAdapter .ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> productList = new ArrayList<String>();
Context mContext;

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

public ImageViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> item) {
    this.productList = item;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int arg1) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_imageview_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imgPeoples;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgPeoples = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//Set image to imageview 

//@Note: here im using universal image loader to load image from url to imageview.

//Utility.setImageUniversalLoader is my methoad to load image from imageurl

   Utility.setImageUniversalLoader(mContext,productList.get(position),holder.imgPeoples);

     }

  }
```

Create single_imageview_row.xml with imageview in layout folder